# вернуть указатель на начало найденного фрагмента

Tags: c++, указатели, динамические-массивы

Объясните, что нужно сделать.
Задание:

> Функция проверяет, является ли массив В подмножеством массива А и
>   возвращает указатель на начало найденного фрагмента.

Как можно вернуть указатель? Если можно, то с примером.
Вот, что получилось, но она конечно же не работает, пожалуйста найдите ошибку

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int* proverca(int* A,int* B, int size1, int size2){
    int* ptr ;
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < size1; i++){
    int j = i, k = 0;
        while(j < size1 && k < size2 && B[k] == A[j]){
            j++;
            k++;            
        }if(k == size2)
            return ptr = A + i;
        else    
            return 0;
    }
}
int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    int size1, size2;
    cout << "Введите размер массива A: ";
    cin >> size1;
    int* A = new int[size1 + 1];
    cout << "Заполните массив: ";
    for(int i = 0; i<size1; i++)
        cin >> A[i];
    cout << "Введите размер массива B: ";
    cin >> size2;
    int* B = new int[size2];
    cout << "Заполните массив: ";
    for(int i = 0; i<size2; i++)
        cin >> B[i];


    cout << "Элемент должен стоять на позиции " << *proverca(A, B, size1, size2) << endl;


    delete []A;
    delete []B;
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: покажите сначала вашу попытку решения ?

Comment: А в чём проблема вернуть указатель? Что именно не выходит? `return (тут ваш указатель)` и всё в общем-то.

Comment: Подмножеством или подпоследовательностью?

Comment: @Cerbo подмножество

Comment: @АсяФилатова Вы пытаетесь найти как раз подпоследовательность, ну и возвращайте индекс А там где начинается Б. Если рассматривать строго множества, то в них по определению не может быть никаких фрагментов и индексов. Так что скажите своему преподавателю чтобы четче задания давал.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблемы в следующем:

```
int* proverca(int* A,int* B, int size1, int size2)
{
    int* ptr ;
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < size1; i++)
    {
        int j = i, k = 0;
        while(j < size1 && k < size2 && B[k] == A[j])
        {
            j++;
            k++;            
        }

        if(k == size2)
           return ptr = A + i;
        //else      
        //   return 0; // эта ветка здесь лишняя, вы возвращаете 0 после
                       // первой же неудачной попытки
    }
    return 0; // она должна быть здесь
}
```

Comment: Да, все заработало, спасибо)

Answer (score 2):

Ваша задача точь в точь описывает поведение алгоритма [std::search](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/search/). Его использование выглядит так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main(){
    int first[10] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    int second[4] = {4, 5, 6, 7};

    int *match = std::search(&first[0], &first[10], &second[0], &second[4]);
}
```

Насколько я понимаю, тот кто выдал вам эту задачу не удовлетворится таким решением:

```
int* search(int *aBegin, int *aEnd, int *bBegin, int *bEnd){
    return std::search(aBegin, aEnd, bBegin, bEnd);
}
```

Хотя чем черт не шутит, можете пробовать блеснуть знанием stl :)

Если вдруг такой вариант не подходит, можно подсмотреть реализацию этого алгоритма по той ссылке, которую я вам дал. Если выкинуть от туда шаблоны, то получится что-то такое:

```
int* search(int *aBegin, int *aEnd, int *bBegin, int *bEnd){
    while (aBegin != aEnd){
        int *it1 = aBegin;
        int *it2 = bBegin;
        while (*it1 == *it2){
            ++it1; 
            ++it2;
            if(it2 == bEnd){
                return aBegin;
            }
            if(it1==aEnd){
                return aEnd;
            }
        }
        ++aBegin;
    }
    return aEnd;
}
```